# Understanding Frobenius's Theorem

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $\Gamma_g$ be the fundamental group of a closed Riemann surface of genus $g$. Let $G$ be a finite group. Then a theorem of Frobenius states that 
$$
|\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma_g, G)|/|G|= \sum_{\chi} \big(|G|/\dim(\chi)\big)^{2g-2}
$$
where $\chi$ ranges over irreducible complex representations of $G$.

Question: What is the correct way to understand this theorem? Can one give a canonical bijection between two sides?

Proofs of this result which I have seen (e.g. the one in the paper of [Hausel-Rodriguez Villegas](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612668)) were not very illuminating for me.

Comment: Minor comment: I thought that people refer to the $g=1$ case as Frobenius's theorem, and the general case as Mednykh's formula.

Comment: One thing is that this formula can be interpreted in terms of $2d$ TQFT.  For instances see Teleman's discussion here https://math.berkeley.edu/~teleman/math/barclect.pdf.

Comment: Proposition I of Aizenbud, Avraham; Avni, Nir_, [**Representation growth and rational singularities of the moduli space of local systems**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00222-015-0614-8), (2016) may be somewhat related to this.